# Confusion about Luttinger's transport coefficients

Tags: temperature, transport-phenomena, quantum-transport

I've started reading three papers, one by [Luttinger](https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.135.A1505), one by [Eich](https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.90.115116) and by [Tatara](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.196601), and I'm confused to how they relate to one another.

My understanding is that in Luttinger's paper a "gravitational" field is added such that it emulates a thermal gradient, by satisfying the Einstein relation. For this he has to introduce a spacial and time varying field $\psi(r,t)$. Tatara tries to also obtain a thermal gradient, but using a vector potential to avoid mathematical problems at zero temperature. He seems to succeed in doing so, and also has to add a time and space varying field. In the end, both try to get a local temperature that changes in space.

Eich on the other hand, seems to do something very different. Instead of a temperature gradient, he has a discrete number of environments, and to each he changes the energies $\epsilon \rightarrow \epsilon + \psi \epsilon$ such that you get a new temperature which is multiplied by $1+\psi$. Here for example, I wouldn't know if this is Luttinger's or Tatara's approach, seem like neither (or that both models would result in the same Hamiltonian). Seems like here he wants a uniform temperature in the environment, therefore he doesn't need the time dependence in the field.

Adding more to my confusion, in Eich's paper he states that in Luttinger's approach "the temperature remains spatially uniform", which to me seems to be the case in his paper and exactly not in Luttinger's (since there he is defining a continuous thermal gradient).

In summary, I'm a bit puzzled on how to connect these two/three formalisms.